# Please explain what happens here: b=[x[:] for x in a]

Tags: python-3.x

I don't quite understand what is happening in the below code. Is it creating a copy of a nested list? If so, how is it doing it? What is b equal to?

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

b = [x[:] for x in a]
```

Comment: This is making a deep copy of the list. By default, l[:] is l[0:len(l)]

Comment: And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) explains why you may want to do this.

Comment: x[:] selects all items in list x, so you're selecting all indexes of list x for x in list a of x's